# Mongo findAndUpdateMany atomically

Tags: mongodb

Let's say there are 10000 documents in a collection. I have 3 app nodes doing something with those documents. I want one document to only be processed once. How I've currently done it is that in app there's a loop which queries the collection with `findOneAndUpdate` which finds document where `claimed=false` and at the same time updates them to `claimed=true`. It works, but the problem with this is querying documents one by one is slow. What I'd like to do is "find up to 100 documents where `claimed=false` and at the same time update them to `claimed=true`". I need this to be atomic to avoid race conditions where multiple app nodes claim the same document. But from Mongo's documentation I can't find anything like `findManyAndUpdate()`. In SQL worlds it's basically `select for update skip locked`. Is there something like this? Maybe I can utilise Mongo's transactions somehow?

Comment: Did you try update? Mongo has update operation which atomic on each document

Comment: Update doesn't have limit. If it would then I'd could hack something together that would act a find and update. Cause remember, i only want to update up to 100 documents not all of them

Comment: Try using Transactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming "find **up to**" a soft limit, you can run 2 queries:

```
db.collection.find({claimed:false}, {_id:1}).limit(100)
```

to get all _ids into an array `ids`, then

```
db.collection.updateMany({claimed: false, _id: {$in: `ids`}}, {$set: {claimed: true}})
```

It will update 0 to 100 documents depending on concurrent updates.

**UPDATE**

I guess I missed the point that you actually need to retrieve the documents too, not only update them.

There is no options but update them individually. Select 100:

```
db.collection.find({claimed:false}).limit(100)
```

Then iterate for each _id:

```
db.collection.updateOne({_id: id, claimed:false}, {$set: {claimed:true}})
```

The result of each update contains `modifiedCount` with value 1 or 0. Discard the documents that were not modified, they were claimed by the concurrent update.

**UPDATE 2**

As [caeus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77114178/1110423) pointed, the most efficient way will be by introducing a technical field `token`:

```
db.collection.find({claimed:false}, {_id:1}).limit(100)
db.collection.updateMany(
    {claimed: false, _id: {$in: `ids`}, token: null}, 
    {$set: {claimed: true, token: token}}
)
const docs = collection.find({token})
```

To follow up comments:

**The "at most once" guarantee test**

Using Atlas test database, the test function to run 3 concurrent updates:

```
exports = async function(arg){
  var serviceName = "mongodb-atlas";
  var dbName = "sample_analytics";
  var collName = "transactions";

  var collection = context.services.get(serviceName).db(dbName).collection(collName);


  let worker = async token => {
    const ids = await collection.find({claimed:null}, {_id:1}).limit(10).toArray();
    for(let one of ids) {
      try {
        let res = await collection.findOneAndUpdate({_id: one._id, claimed:null}, {$set: {claimed:token}}, { returnOriginal: false });
        console.log(JSON.stringify({token, id: one._id, res: res}));
      } catch(e) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify({token, id: one._id, res: "ignored concurrent update"}));
      }
    }        
  }
    
  await Promise.all([
    worker(1),
    worker(2),
    worker(3)
    ])

  return { "result": "ok" };
};
```

results:

```
{"token":3,"id":"5ca4bbc1a2dd94ee58161cd0","res":{"_id":"5ca4bbc1a2dd94ee58161cd0","account_id":209363,"transaction_count":56,"bucket_start_date":"1972-04-28T00:00:00.000Z","bucket_end_date":"2016-12-31T00:00:00.000Z","transactions":[{"date":"2011-12-29T00:00:00.000Z","amount":4210,"transaction_code":"sell","symbol":"nvda","price":"12.7053041869746241587790791527368128299713134765625","total":"53489.33062716316770845992323"},{"date":"2007-05-08T00:00:00.000Z","amount":7082,"transaction_code":"sell","symbol":"ebay","price":"14.515855208410716414846319821663200855255126953125","total":"102801.2865859646936499416370"},{"date":"2014-12-26T00:00:00.000Z","amount":2897,"transaction_code":"buy","symbol":"nvda","price":"19.9329107151621158777743403334170579910278320
{"token":2,"id":"5ca4bbc1a2dd94ee58161cd0","res":"ignored concurrent update"}
{"token":1,"id":"5ca4bbc1a2dd94ee58161cd0","res":"ignored concurrent update"}
{"token":1,"id":"5ca4bbc1a2dd94ee58161cd1","res":{"_id":"5ca4bbc1a2dd94ee58161cd1","account_id":556654,"transaction_count":5,"bucket_start_date":"1998-11-03T00:00:00.000Z","bucket_end_date":"2016-06-03T00:00:00.000Z","transactions":[{"date":"2015-06-02T00:00:00.000Z","amount":6151,"transaction_code":"sell","symbol":"crm","price":"72.8426439346270200303479214198887348175048828125","total":"448055.1028418908002066700647"},{"date":"2014-12-01T00:00:00.000Z","amount":9275,"transaction_code":"buy","symbol":"msft","price":"44.69693492546749524763072258792817592620849609375","total":"414564.0714337110184217749520"},{"date":"2015-12-15T00:00:00.000Z","amount":647,"transaction_code":"buy","symbol":"sap","price":"76.1444367496054184130116482265293598175048828125","tot
{"token":2,"id":"5ca4bbc1a2dd94ee58161cd1","res":"ignored concurrent update"}
{"token":3,"id":"5ca4bbc1a2dd94ee58161cd1","res":"ignored concurrent update"}
{"token":1,"id":"5ca4bbc1a2dd94ee58161cd2","res":{"_id":"5ca4bbc1a2dd94ee58161cd2","account_id":433314,"transaction_count":79,"bucket_start_date":"1988-01-31T00:00:00.000Z","bucket_end_date":"2017-01-06T00:00:00.000Z","transactions":[{"date":"2012-08-20T00:00:00.000Z","amount":1840,"transaction_code":"buy","symbol":"sap","price":"60.72338790387646412227695691399276256561279296875","total":"111731.0337431326939849896007"},{"date":"2011-11-23T00:00:00.000Z","amount":9039,"transaction_code":"buy","symbol":"crm","price":"26.10434595091344789352660882286727428436279296875","total":"235957.1830503066555095870171"},{"date":"2013-07-10T00:00:00.000Z","amount":2797,"transaction_code":"sell","symbol":"crm","price":"39.626144806625916316988877952098846435546875","total
{"token":2,"id":"5ca4bbc1a2dd94ee58161cd2","res":"ignored concurrent update"}
{"token":3,"id":"5ca4bbc1a2dd94ee58161cd2","res":"ignored concurrent update"}
{"token":3,"id":"5ca4bbc1a2dd94ee58161cd3","res":{"_id":"5ca4bbc1a2dd94ee58161cd3","account_id":328304,"transaction_count":62,"bucket_start_date":"1989-03-16T00:00:00.000Z","bucket_end_date":"2017-01-04T00:00:00.000Z","transactions":[{"date":"2013-04-02T00:00:00.000Z","amount":982,"transaction_code":"buy","symbol":"adbe","price":"43.616037395583163061019149608910083770751953125","total":"42830.94872246266612592080492"},{"date":"2014-04-11T00:00:00.000Z","amount":7479,"transaction_code":"sell","symbol":"ebay","price":"22.542338607107371473148305085487663745880126953125","total":"168594.1504425560312476761737"},{"date":"2003-10-03T00:00:00.000Z","amount":873,"transaction_code":"buy","symbol":"adbe","price":"20.300427787642245647248273598961532115936279296875",
{"token":2,"id":"5ca4bbc1a2dd94ee58161cd3","res":"ignored concurrent update"}
{"token":1,"id":"5ca4bbc1a2dd94ee58161cd3","res":"ignored concurrent update"}
{"token":1,"id":"5ca4bbc1a2dd94ee58161cd4","res":{"_id":"5ca4bbc1a2dd94ee58161cd4","account_id":491860,"transaction_count":15,"bucket_start_date":"1985-05-31T00:00:00.000Z","bucket_end_date":"2016-02-29T00:00:00.000Z","transactions":[{"date":"2014-04-22T00:00:00.000Z","amount":9734,"transaction_code":"sell","symbol":"csco","price":"20.9854303178432672893904964439570903778076171875","total":"204272.1787138863637949270924"},{"date":"2003-10-27T00:00:00.000Z","amount":897,"transaction_code":"buy","symbol":"amd","price":"13.9268795524194164414666374796070158481597900390625","total":"12492.41095852021654799557382"},{"date":"2013-04-02T00:00:00.000Z","amount":9879,"transaction_code":"sell","symbol":"amd","price":"2.4426151556730935077155209000920876860618591308593
{"token":2,"id":"5ca4bbc1a2dd94ee58161cd4","res":"ignored concurrent update"}
{"token":3,"id":"5ca4bbc1a2dd94ee58161cd4","res":"ignored concurrent update"}
{"token":1,"id":"5ca4bbc1a2dd94ee58161cd5","res":{"_id":"5ca4bbc1a2dd94ee58161cd5","account_id":463155,"transaction_count":9,"bucket_start_date":"1983-11-23T00:00:00.000Z","bucket_end_date":"2015-10-26T00:00:00.000Z","transactions":[{"date":"2009-02-03T00:00:00.000Z","amount":7581,"transaction_code":"sell","symbol":"ebay","price":"5.2600884272046943834766352665610611438751220703125","total":"39876.73036663878812113637196"},{"date":"1998-05-21T00:00:00.000Z","amount":6691,"transaction_code":"buy","symbol":"amd","price":"10.4532134015998909859490595408715307712554931640625","total":"69942.45087010487058698515739"},{"date":"1986-07-17T00:00:00.000Z","amount":9759,"transaction_code":"sell","symbol":"amd","price":"7.37200706508668979211051919264718890190124511718
{"token":2,"id":"5ca4bbc1a2dd94ee58161cd5","res":"ignored concurrent update"}
{"token":3,"id":"5ca4bbc1a2dd94ee58161cd5","res":"ignored concurrent update"}
{"token":2,"id":"5ca4bbc1a2dd94ee58161cd6","res":{"_id":"5ca4bbc1a2dd94ee58161cd6","account_id":487188,"transaction_count":73,"bucket_start_date":"1987-07-11T00:00:00.000Z","bucket_end_date":"2017-01-06T00:00:00.000Z","transactions":[{"date":"2015-09-21T00:00:00.000Z","amount":3471,"transaction_code":"sell","symbol":"ebay","price":"26.263634559655628208929556421935558319091796875","total":"91161.07555656468551319449034"},{"date":"2010-01-21T00:00:00.000Z","amount":4474,"transaction_code":"buy","symbol":"amzn","price":"125.98202606186947605237946845591068267822265625","total":"563643.5846008040358583457419"},{"date":"2002-01-17T00:00:00.000Z","amount":854,"transaction_code":"sell","symbol":"adbe","price":"17.74118706057874561565768090076744556427001953125","t
{"token":1,"id":"5ca4bbc1a2dd94ee58161cd6","res":"ignored concurrent update"}
{"token":3,"id":"5ca4bbc1a2dd94ee58161cd6","res":"ignored concurrent update"}
{"token":1,"id":"5ca4bbc1a2dd94ee58161cd8","res":"ignored concurrent update"}
{"token":2,"id":"5ca4bbc1a2dd94ee58161cd8","res":"ignored concurrent update"}
{"token":3,"id":"5ca4bbc1a2dd94ee58161cd8","res":{"_id":"5ca4bbc1a2dd94ee58161cd8","account_id":729049,"transaction_count":76,"bucket_start_date":"1974-06-18T00:00:00.000Z","bucket_end_date":"2016-12-25T00:00:00.000Z","transactions":[{"date":"2007-07-24T00:00:00.000Z","amount":6309,"transaction_code":"sell","symbol":"intc","price":"19.64081577660875410629159887321293354034423828125","total":"123913.9067346246296565936973"},{"date":"2015-11-20T00:00:00.000Z","amount":8610,"transaction_code":"buy","symbol":"nvda","price":"31.16714754376160811943918815813958644866943359375","total":"268349.1403517874459083714100"},{"date":"2006-04-28T00:00:00.000Z","amount":341,"transaction_code":"buy","symbol":"adbe","price":"39.4691017552187730643709073774516582489013671875",
{"token":2,"id":"5ca4bbc1a2dd94ee58161cd9","res":{"_id":"5ca4bbc1a2dd94ee58161cd9","account_id":149440,"transaction_count":8,"bucket_start_date":"1999-07-01T00:00:00.000Z","bucket_end_date":"2016-05-30T00:00:00.000Z","transactions":[{"date":"2015-09-08T00:00:00.000Z","amount":1641,"transaction_code":"buy","symbol":"goog","price":"606.348321107741639934829436242580413818359375","total":"995017.5949378040311330551049"},{"date":"2007-04-10T00:00:00.000Z","amount":7912,"transaction_code":"buy","symbol":"amzn","price":"41.540727537577140537905506789684295654296875","total":"328670.2362773103359359083697"},{"date":"2007-01-11T00:00:00.000Z","amount":3666,"transaction_code":"sell","symbol":"csco","price":"23.814660969086471453692865907214581966400146484375","total"
{"token":3,"id":"5ca4bbc1a2dd94ee58161cd9","res":"ignored concurrent update"}
{"token":1,"id":"5ca4bbc1a2dd94ee58161cd9","res":"ignored concurrent update"}
{"token":3,"id":"5ca4bbc1a2dd94ee58161cda","res":{"_id":"5ca4bbc1a2dd94ee58161cda","account_id":701440,"transaction_count":34,"bucket_start_date":"1971-12-06T00:00:00.000Z","bucket_end_date":"2017-01-02T00:00:00.000Z","transactions":[{"date":"2016-08-19T00:00:00.000Z","amount":885,"transaction_code":"sell","symbol":"goog","price":"773.7978783374882141288253478705883026123046875","total":"684811.1223286770695040104329"},{"date":"2016-01-05T00:00:00.000Z","amount":4635,"transaction_code":"buy","symbol":"sap","price":"74.7571188147861249717607279308140277862548828125","total":"346499.2457065336892441109740"},{"date":"1972-09-11T00:00:00.000Z","amount":1776,"transaction_code":"buy","symbol":"ibm","price":"16.3644365038663437417199020273983478546142578125","total
{"token":2,"id":"5ca4bbc1a2dd94ee58161cda","res":"ignored concurrent update"}
{"token":1,"id":"5ca4bbc1a2dd94ee58161cda","res":"ignored concurrent update"}
```

Comment: This solution is not atomic...

Comment: @nimrodserok it is on document level.

Comment: @AlexBlex But that's not enough in my case. I need to lock 100 documents with the certainity that noone else locks none of them at the same time. Currently I can only lock one.

Comment: @Tarmo, yes, you lock 1 at a time, there is no workaround. The only improvement I propose it to select all 100 in one go, and use _id in the update to benefit from the unique index. Should be a bit faster, with the caveat that it may be less than 100 if there are concurrent updates. I emphasised that "up to 100", not "exact 100"  is the critical part for this approach.

Comment: Ok. No I understand.. This will actually work. But I highly doubt it would be lot faster that my original solution where I just do `findOneAndUpdate`. Cause still there are lot of roundtrips involved. But by now I acknowledge that this might be the best we've got at the moment.

Comment: It is not atomic on document level. If two instances are making the same query/update, there's a big chance multiple documents will be processed more than once.

Comment: @caeus I don't see a link between the 2 sentences in your comment. The first one is plainly wrong - mongodb guarantees atomicity of write operations on document level. The second sentence is correct - please re-read and try to comprehend the whole answer. I emphasised on "up to"  part at the beginning, and how to discard duplicated updates at the end of the answer. Read the comments as well.

Comment: Don't take it personal. Mongo doesn't have a findManyAndUpdate operation. Also the two solutions you offer have problems. First solution may cause documents to be re processed, so no "at most once" semantics guaranteed. Second solution does work, but it won't scale given that for every batch, I have to make N+1 requests. The ideal would be a findManyAndUpdate, a single operation, but that's not possible. So with a token, that can be reduced to two operations, and be atomic enough to guarantee "at most once" semantics.

Comment: @caeus please ignore my tone if it sounds offensive/protective or whatever it looks. It's cultural =) I am here to learn on other people mistakes, and any feedback is welcome, especially if it proves me wrong.  Now the `updateMany({claimed: false, _id: {$in: ids}}, {$set: {claimed: true}})` will not process a document more than ones regardless how many parallel updates are running. The more intersection in the `$in: ids` in parallel queries the less documents are going to be updated by individual threads. This is how atomicity of document writes work.

Comment: yes, it will. Imagine two processes getting unclaimed IDs at the same time. They'll most likely get the same IDs... they'll do the following update, and that will work ok, but both processes got the same IDs, so if what the original poster is trying to implement is actually a queue with an "at most once" guarantee, this approach won't work. I will try to find a mongo fiddle and show you

Comment: @caeus please do

Answer (score 2):

You may add some sort of token to the formula.

something like:

```js
const token = generateUniqueToken()
collection.updateMany({token:null},
{$set:{token}})

const docs = collection.find({token})
```

Pretty sure you can limit the number of documents updated.

This is still NOT 100% atomic in the sense that if something fails in between the update and the read, docs may be missed.

Yet this ensures that documents will be processed at most once.

Comment: How "token" is better than "claimed" ?

Comment: claimed is only `true` or `false`. "token" can be anything... it's actually an identifiear. I first "claim" N documents with `updateMany` (only documents with token null), Later on I can know EXACTLY which documents I updated,  by querying on said token. And that's only TWO request to mongo, instead of a N+1, requests. Also better than your first option which clearly suffers from race conditions, in case more than one process makes the same requests simultaneously.

Comment: yep, makes sense, it should be more efficient. It will be 3 requests as you need to fetch ids first, but it's definitely better than N+1 updateOnes

Comment: pretty good answer and I was considering doing something like this myself. The "token" could be a server id/thread id or something similar, or a sufficiently random value