# make repository mutually exclusive in springboot

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

Is there a way to make a  repository mutually exclusive i.e two concurrent values not update the same document in Springboot.
My code structure is.

```
//func(version,cid)
//make a api call for cid
//fetch the document with that version
//update the document with result against the cid
```

all API calls are concurrently editing the same document

ps: I can share code if needed.
[database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jz1YK.png)

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72097130/mongo-findandupdatemany-atomically) what you were looking for?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.